# Office addins using Office JS

Tags: office-js, office-addins

Two questions.

1. How can I set a title in office JS App taskpane different to AppName? i Have multiple taskpanes and each one should have different headers.
2. How can I limit the app to only MAC or IPad?

Comment: If you already have multiple taskpanes app, why would you try it yourself? And you cannot limit the app for one platform only.

Answer (score 0):

1. you cannot change the title in the task pane programmatically. Please use our [uservoice channel to create or upvote this request](https://officespdev.uservoice.com/).
2. You cannot limit your add-in to a specific platform, but you could get the platform at runtime by checking Office.context.diagnostics.platform and then provide a limiting experience/ui to users on non-supported platforms.